# Cut down binwalk extracted files

Tags: reverse-engineer, binwalk

When extracting image files from a firmware dump using binwalk, I get a lot of valid pngs. My problem is the following: All those files are extremely large. They start with the correct beginning but are as long as the rest of the dump. How do I cut those files automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often you can use an image converter to convert the PNG's to ... PNG's.

Many image 'processors' will read the image based on the headers in the image file itself, which means they'll only read what is needed to load the picture.  Then re-save the image, perhaps to a new name.

I created a `fat PNG` (ha!) by `cat`ing several files together, a PNG, and then a 3Meg PDF.

- `feh` loads the image just fine
- `gimp` loads the image, and saves it properly, dropping the extra garbage.
- `convert` (from `imagemagick` package) works well, `convert fat.png jcraig.png` strips off the extra.
- `gwenview` (KDE app) read and saved the file properly.

I only tried the few applications I could think of that I knew I had installed.   The `imagemagick` utility `convert` is promising and scriptable.

```
for f in *.png; do
  convert "$f" "skinny.$f"
done
```

Probably make light work of your weighty images.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I guessed. Of course, this works only on lossless compressed files. Do you have any idea what to do with other file types?

Comment: it should work on any file type that has length/size headers.  GIF/JPG/PNG/BMP/TIFF/PBM/PPM/PGM... and so on. Even XPM's can be easily recovered (but they're all text anyways).  Zip files have length descriptions... about the only thing that might not be as easy would be perhaps an executable, although if you could parse the initial data, they too indicate how long they are. I can envision how to recover almost any file if it starts at the beginning of the file and is longer than necessary.  Definitely Do-able.  The images are easiest since the utils truncate the files properly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question but arrived at a perhaps more elegant answer.

```
binwalk -D 'png:png:convert %e %e' myfile.bin
```

That will run the `convert` program in place on any extracted PNG files.

Comment: Actually I ended up writing my own C program that strips PNGs. I may post it here if I remember...